# Alert inside java code is not displaying in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to display alert message if lenderId is null, but I am not able to display alert with below code. In **MYfile.jsp**

```
<%
  Long lenderId  = SessionUtil.getLenderOfferId(request);
 %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var Msg = '<%=SessionUtil.getLenderOfferId(request)%>';
    if (Msg == "null") {
      function alertName() {
        alert("Session Expired");
      }
    }
  </script>
  <%
    ------
    ----
    %>
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (Msg == "null") {
        function alertName(){
          alert("Session Expired");
        } 
     }
```

You need not to create a function inside if condition. Just alert it directly

```
  if (Msg == "null") {    
       alert("Session Expired");
     }
```

Comment: No, Even after removing function name, alert is not displaying in browser.

Comment: @daisy Do you have a look at browser console ?? Any errors ?

Comment: @daisy And what about the value od Msg ? is it "null" ?

Comment: lenderId is null, by the way  var Msg = '<%=SessionUtil.getLenderOfferId(request)%>'; is this correct to use inside script tag.? and i am not geting any errors.

Comment: .SessionUtil.getLenderOfferId(request) returns Long not a string. So is it causing this error? inside script tag nothing is exceuting. And i can say lenderId is null  because when i print using SYSOUT inside <% java code%> there i get null and it is actually.

Comment: @daisy Without the null condition, can you just directly alert the `Msg` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164690/discussion-between-daisy-and--).